# Modifying the contents of a .cpp file

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

UPDATE: I am now able to compile the .cpp file with make
(I can see the compilation output). However, the changes does not seem to take affect.
After i run make, i restart the computer, but still no changes.

As you probably understand, I have very limited experience with c++. 
I am currently working on a project (OpenBTS) and have found an error in one of the .cpp files after the project has been built and installed. 
My question is, how can I modify the contents (f.eks change the string of a JSON data reference) of a .cpp file and build it so I can see the changes afterwards?

I have currently tried the following:

```
1.
make 'filename.cpp'
make: Nothing to be done for 'filename.cpp'

2.
make 'filename'
g++ 'filename.cpp' -o 'filename'
In file included from 'filename.cpp:29:0:
'filname.h':26:21: fatal error: Timeval.h: No such file or directory
#include <Timeval.h>
compilation terminated.

3. Run make from root directory:
Nothing to be done for 'all.'

4. Run make clean and make from root. This rebuilds the project but the
changes are still not in effect (I can see that the JSON String is not
changed at the webserver).

5. Run ./build.sh script. Still no changes.
```

Regarding the 2. method, as the project was built and compiled successfully, how come when i try that with a single file, the compiler can't find the header files? The only thing i changed was a string from "ARFCN" to "ARFCNtest".
Since there are about 50 header files that depends on each other, changing the include from <> to "" and copy every single file into the same directory seems like a waste and unnecessary action?

Comment: I have no experience with OpenBTS but "make clean" followed by "make" should almost certainly do it, however, are you then _installing_ (or otherwise deploying) the modified package that you've just built? Did you stop the original process and relaunch etc?

Comment: The .cpp file I am trying to modify is sending JSON data to a webserver, so the only think i tried after "make clean" and "make" was to restart the computer. But I still can't see any changes in the JSON data which must mean the .cpp file hasn't been compiled or?

Comment: Doesn't sound particularly likely; you wouldn't normally build something "in place" (maybe for some dynamic language frameworks, but not generally for C/C++ projects). I strongly suspect you need to copy the built binary to the correct location before restarting. Try `ps -Af` on the command line to see what's actually running and find your application's pid, then check its `/proc` entry (`/proc/xxx/self`) to find the link to the binary.

Comment: Thank you @davmac, i will certainly try that!

Comment: (should be `/proc/xxx/exe`, not `/proc/xxx/self`, sorry!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes didn't take effect because the compilation failed. See the error message you quoted in the question. Fix that and rebuild.

Incidentally, restarting your computer shouldn't be necessary. Even the `make clean` shouldn't be necessary if the `Makefile` correctly expresses the dependencies. (It seems to do so in this case since it *tried* to recompile the source file you modified.)